# Prove that $7|3^{41}-5$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I am trying to prove that $7|3^{41}-5$. 

The way I have been approaching this problem is by trying to factor the exponent of $41$ into a product of smaller exponents that will help me find a number that is divisible by $7$ with a remainder of $5.$

I have not gotten far, but my idea is:

$3^{41} = (3^{2})^{20}\times 3 - 5$

The part that I am getting hung up on is the fact that $41$ is a prime number. In my class, we have done examples where the exponent is factorable, so there is not a lingering 3 being multiplied into the factored exponent. I believe I understand the process of how this works when the exponent is not a prime number, but I cannot seem to understand how to accomplish this proof given these parameters.

We have covered modular arithmetic in this class and I am thinking maybe I should be using that to handle this problem, but I am not sure how to do so.

Comment: The usual way to do it is to note that the residues of $3^a$ when dividing by $7$ start to cycle: $\color{red}{3,2,6,4,5,1},\color{blue}{3,2,6,4,5,1,}\color{red}{3,2,6,4,5,1},\color{blue}{3,2,6,4,5,1} \dots$ . Although the highly trained professionals use this theorem instead: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem

Comment: Hint: $7\mid 3n\Rightarrow 7\mid n,\,$ and $7\mid 3n$ by $3^6\equiv 1$ by little Fermat (or $3^3\equiv -1$ directly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the usual approach for this sort of problem is to use [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

However, we can solve it using your idea:

$$3^{41} = (3^{2})^{20}\times 3 - 5$$
Now
$$3^2 = 9 \equiv 2 \pmod 7$$
So
$$3^{20} \equiv 2^{10} = 1024 \pmod 7$$
But
$$1024 = 7\times 146 + 2$$
i.e.,
$$1024 \equiv 2 \pmod 7$$
So
$$3^{40} \equiv 2^2 = 4 \pmod 7$$
And
$$3^{41} \equiv 12 \equiv 5 \pmod 7$$
Therefore
$$3^{41} - 5 \equiv 0 \pmod 7$$

Answer (score 3):

Fermat's little theorem:  since $7$ is prime, we have $3^6\equiv1\pmod7$.  Thus $3^{42}\equiv(3^6)^7\equiv1$.  Thus we just need to "divide by $3$".  What's the inverse of $3 \pmod7$?  It's $5$, since $5\cdot3\equiv15\equiv1\pmod7$.  Thus we get the result.

Answer (score 2):

**Without using specific theorems**

Observe that:

$$\frac{3^{41}-5}{7}  \in\mathbb Z\iff \frac{3^{41}+2}{7}  \in\mathbb Z $$

$$k=\frac{3^5+2}{7} =35 \in\mathbb Z$$

Then, we have

$$\begin{align}\frac{3^{41}-5}{7} 
&\equiv \frac{3(7k-2)^8+2}{7}\\
&\equiv \frac{3×2^8+2}{7}\\
&\equiv \frac{3×2^7+1}{7}\\
&=55 \in\mathbb Z.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

$3^5+2=245\equiv0\pmod7$, so $0\equiv(3^5+2)(3^5-2)=3^{10}-4$,

so $3^{20}-2\equiv3^{20}-16= (3^{10}-4)(3^{10}+4)\equiv0\pmod7$,

so $3^{40}-4=(3^{20}-2)(3^{20}+2)\equiv0\pmod7$,

so $3^{41}-5\equiv3^{41}-12\equiv0\pmod7$.

Answer (score 1):

Without Fermat little theorem approach. Having $a^n + 1 = (a+1)(a^{n-1}-...+1)$, one have:
$$ 3^{41} - 5 =  9(3^{39} + 1) - 14=  9(27^{13}+1) - 14 \equiv 0 \mod 7$$

Comment: the signs alternate, $a^n+1=(a+1)(a^n-..+1)$

Comment: Fixed. Thank you. And hope you're pleased to remove the downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvote in the first place ;) +1 anyway

Answer (score 1):

We can use Fermat's Little Theorem to see that $3^6 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$ and so $7|3^6 - 1$.

Or we can observe by simply looking at the first few powers of $3$ that $3^3 \equiv -1$ and so $7|3^3 + 1 = 28$.

Either way that implies that $7|3^{42} -1 = (3^6 - 1)(3^{36} + 3^{30} + ...+ 3^6 + 1)= (3^3 + 1)(3^{39}-3^{36} + 3^{33} -.... -3^6 +3^3 - 1)$

Now we can try to manipulate $x = 3^{41}-5$ to get $3^{42}-1$.

$3x = 3^{42} - 15$ and $3x + 14 = 3^{42} - 1$.

So $7|14$ and $7| 3^{42} -1$ so $7|(3^{42}-1)-14 = 3x$.

But $7$ is prime so $7|3x\implies 7|3$ or $7|x$.  As $7\not \mid 3$ we must have $7|x = 3^{41}-5$.

.......

Furthermore:  We can actually find the value of $(3^{41} - 5)\div 7$.

$3^{42}-1= (3^6 - 1)(3^{36} + 3^{30} + ...+ 3^6 + 1)=$

$(3^3 + 1)(3^3-1)(3^{36} + 3^{30} + ...+ 3^6 + 1)=$

$=4\cdot 7\cdot (3^3-1)(3^{36} + 3^{30} + ...+ 3^6 + 1)=$

$3^{42}-15 = 7[4(3^3-1)(3^{36} + 3^{30} + ...+ 3^6 + 1)-2]=$

$3^{41}-5 = 7\frac {4(3^3-1)(3^{36} + 3^{30} + ...+ 3^6 + 1)-2}3=$

$7[(3^3-1)(3^{36} + 3^{30} + ...+ 3^6 + 1)+ \frac {(3^3-1)(3^{36} + 3^{30} + ...+ 3^6 + 1)-2}3]=$

$7[(3^3-1)(3^{36} + 3^{30} + ...+ 3^6 + 1)+\frac {3^3(3^{36} + 3^{30} + ...+ 3^6 + 1) - (3^{36} + 3^{30} + ...+ 3^6 + 1)-2}3=$

$7[26(3^{36} + 3^{30} + ...+ 3^6 + 1) + 9(3^{36} + 3^{30} + ...+ 3^6 + 1)-(3^{35}+3^{29} +.... + 3^5 + 1)]=$

$7[35(3^{36} + 3^{30} + .... + 3^6 + 1) - (3^{35} + 3^{29} + ... + 3^5 + 1)]=$

$7(102(3^{35} + 3^{29} + .....  + 3^5) +34)$.